# replacing content that after specific string in a file using linux

Tags: bash

How to replace a string in file that comes after a specific string.

Content in file1 is as below

```
test= status
```

Content in file2 has just single word and is dynamic.So, my script should read the file2, copy the content and place it after 'test= ' in file1.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Is `successful` the only contents of file2? Shall `test=` reflect that content independent of it's value?

Comment: my mistake, i am soryy for that. I want it in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

```
$content1 = Get-Content file1 #$content1 = 'test= status'
$content2 = Get-Content file2 #$content2 = 'successful'
$result = $content1 -replace '(?<=test= )(.*)',$content2
$result | Set-Content file1
```

`Get-Content` gets content of the file `file1` and `file2`. Then, using `-replace` operator, replace anything preceded by `test=` (see Regex positive lookbehind) with contents of the second file. Final step is writing the result to `file1` using `Set-Content`.

Comment: Nearly exactly my approach (+1), which took a bit to fire up my Ubuntu-VM. As a one liner: `(gc ./file1) -replace "(?<=^test=).*$","$(gc ./file2)"|Set-Content ./file1`